# Page doesn't refresh on gridview button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview, refresh

I already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839934/button-does-not-submit-on-first-click-but-on-subsequent-click-submits-previous) about this problem, but as I progressed in my web application I stumbled across this problem again, because the answer there gave me a new problem. With that solution, I had the problem that the update button did not read the new value in the textbox of my gridview, but instead it read the old value.

**CodeBehind**

With this it doesn't use the new value:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataBinder();
        }
    }

    private void DataBinder()
    {
        Grid30.DataBind();
        Grid31.DataBind();
        Grid32.DataBind();
        Grid33.DataBind();
        Grid34.DataBind();
        Grid35.DataBind();
        Grid36.DataBind();
        Grid37.DataBind();
        Grid38.DataBind();
        Grid40.DataBind();
        Grid41.DataBind();
        Grid42.DataBind();
        Grid43.DataBind();
        Grid44.DataBind();
        Grid45.DataBind();
        Grid51.DataBind();
        Grid52.DataBind();
        Grid53.DataBind();
        Grid54.DataBind();
        Grid55.DataBind();
        Grid56.DataBind();
        Grid57.DataBind();
        Grid58.DataBind();
        Grid61.DataBind();
        Grid62.DataBind();
        Grid63.DataBind();
        Grid64.DataBind();
    }
```

And with this it gets the new value, but it no longer refreshes:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
        DataBinder();

    }

    private void DataBinder()
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Grid30.DataBind();
            Grid31.DataBind();
            Grid32.DataBind();
            Grid33.DataBind();
            Grid34.DataBind();
            Grid35.DataBind();
            Grid36.DataBind();
            Grid37.DataBind();
            Grid38.DataBind();
            Grid40.DataBind();
            Grid41.DataBind();
            Grid42.DataBind();
            Grid43.DataBind();
            Grid44.DataBind();
            Grid45.DataBind();
            Grid51.DataBind();
            Grid52.DataBind();
            Grid53.DataBind();
            Grid54.DataBind();
            Grid55.DataBind();
            Grid56.DataBind();
            Grid57.DataBind();
            Grid58.DataBind();
            Grid61.DataBind();
            Grid62.DataBind();
            Grid63.DataBind();
            Grid64.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

**Update/LoadData Code**

```
    protected void Grid36_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = Grid36.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        var txtQuantity = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Spoor36TB");
        int quantity = int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text);

        Grid36.EditIndex = -1;
        DataBinder();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        foreach(Rail rail in getAllPositions())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rail.RailNr.ToString(), typeof(string)));
            for (int i = 0; i < rail.AmountOfPositions; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[rail.RailNr.ToString()] = "1";
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            DataSources(rail.RailNr, dt);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Well I removed the DataBinder(); under Grid36_RowEditing(). This is no real solution, but a bad workaround for the moment. Now I have to push the edit button twice, but atleast I'm able to Update the grid. This is no/a horrible solution for my problem though, I hope someone will still be able to give me a real solution

```
    protected void Grid36_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid36.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //DataBinder();
    }
```

Comment: your code from the databind ONLY executes when it's the initial load as you state if it's NOT a postback.

Comment: Why do you call `LoadData` on postbacks? You should put that also in the `!PostBack`-check. In general: don't reload data on postbacks from `Page_Load` when ViewState is enabled(default).

Comment: What is your LoadData Doing.. also if it's not a PostBack of course it's going to work.. so you need to add logic that will load regardless if it's a postaback or not or write logic that will check If IsPostBack, and store the value in a Session variable if needed.. you need to show what LoadData(); method looks like

Comment: LoadData has been added to the post, it adds cells to the gridviews. I put a 1 in every cell just for testing. Soon the data for these cells will be called from the database

Comment: @TimSchmelter If I put that in the !PostBack-check it removes all my grids when i click on a button in any gridview

Answer (score 0):

In Row updating method, Update the value in the database and then execute datasource as well as databind method.

Example :-

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
int id = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
TextBox tname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("nam");
TextBox tques = (TextBox)row.FindControl("que");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update exam set name1=@name,ques=@ques where id = @id", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = id;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = tname.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ques", MySqlDbType.VarChar,40).Value = tques.Text.Trim();
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
// Bind grid now
 GridView1.DataSource= dt; // get data from database
 GridView1.Databind();
```